# How to connect registration form to MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, html, mysql, xampp

I want to know how to connect the following code to MySQL by using Python as the server side scripting.

```html
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <label style="font-size:22px;">Sign Up</label><br><br>
            First name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname" required/><br>
            Last name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname" required/><br>
            E-mail:
            <input type="email" name="email" required/><br>
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="pwd" required/><br>
            Gender:
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="yes" required/> I agree to the Terms & Conditions
            <input type="submit" style="width:45%;height:10%">
            <input type="reset" style="width:45%;height:10%">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: [mysql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) or [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/) are the libraries you can use. This is independent of the html programming you've included as a client side.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code ?

Comment: You're not asking for help with small quantifiable problem, you want code written in python (which isn't was is presented here as a starting point). This is outside the scope of stack overflow.